# restrict view based on user's value in model using rules in controller- yii

Tags: yii

Is there a way to restrict view based on user's input in model in the controller?
I want to hide/show their own page based on their own choice. 
profile_hide_show with values of 'p'=>public, 'f'=>friends, and 'm'=>me

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow',
            'actions'=>array('view'),
            'users'=>array('?'), //?based on user's selection in model,
        ),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Yii access control allows you to perform basic control before descending into the local methods of the controller.

You can enable access control by using the 'expression' attribute of an access control list. For example :

```
public function accessRules(){
$owner_id = $this->loadModel()->owner_id;
return array(
        array('allow', 
                'actions'=>array('action1'),
                'expression'=>"{$user->id}=={$owner_id}",
             ),
        array('allow', 
                'actions'=>array('action2'),
                'expression'=>'(Yii::app()->user->id == ($_GET[\'id\']))',
             ),
        array('allow', 
                'actions'=>array('action3'),
                'expression'=>'"Yii::app()->controller->isEnabledByUser()',
             )

);
}
```

If you see the expression for action3, you will see you can call functions that will return a true/false value that will be evaluated by the expression attribute.

```
public function isEnabledByUser(){
    $user_id = Yii::app()->user->id;
    $user    = User::model()->findByPk($user_id); 
    if ($user->show_my_page == 'Y')
       return true;
    else
       return false;
}
```

References
[How to view data only made by the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21180602/how-to-view-data-only-made-by-the-user)

Answer (score 0):

Do this check in the action or loadModel function. You cannot access a model in the accessRules.

```
public function loadModel($id) {

    $type = modelname();
    $class = CActiveRecord::model($type);
    $model = $class->findByPk($id);

    if($model === null)
        throw new CHttpException(404, 'The requested page does not exist.');

    if($model->profile_hide_show != 'p')
        throw new CHttpException(404, 'You cannot view this profile.');

    return $model;
}
```